# Problem using the JPlayer audio player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, jplayer

I'm trying to use the JPlayer (http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/) jQuery plugin and having some trouble using it when it falls back to the Flash SWF.  In that case I hit an error `m.fl_play_mp3 is undefined` which I've traced back to possibly a problem with the path to the SWF file.  However, I've put the full path to the SWF directly in the `embed` tag, it still doesn't work.  When I copy that full path in the `src` into a browser window, I get the Flash object. So what's the best way to debug next?

Is there a way I can verify that the < embed> tag actually was able to load the Flash file?

Can I introspect what methods the compiled SWF exposes?

**UPDATE:** I checked the Firebug Net tab, and the SWF file is downloaded.  So there must be another problem.  The error happens in the jPlayer.js file and I hit this error when I try this demo: http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/0.2.5/demo-07.htm.  I'm using Firefox 3.6 on Snow Leopard.  The line that fails is the fourth one in the snippet below:

```
play: function(e) {
    var fid = $(this).data("jPlayer.config").fid;
 var m = $(this).data("jPlayer.getMovie")(fid);
 var r = m.fl_play_mp3(); // error occurs here
 if(r) {
     $(this).trigger("jPlayer.setButtons", true);
 }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:** I was able to get around this problem by feeding the jPlayer a mp3 file instead of a wav file. Doesn't answer my question, but at least fixes this problem.

Comment: Use Firebug's net tab to check whether the flash file was loaded. And who gives you `m.fl_play_mp3 is undefined`? Javascript? Calling from where? Can you show the code?

Comment: Paste your code, it could help.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that it just doesn't play music when it's using the flash version?  That's because it looks for the music relative to the SWF file in this case, not the html.  It's probably not finding your music if you're using a relative path as the mp3 path instead of an http link.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that is you must supply an alternative file type to replace wav when the player falls back to flash. Wav playback is only supported in some HTML5 browsers, but NOT by flash.

You do this with the [supplied](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-option-supplied) option. This tell the player what types to use and the priority.

If you supply it wav and mp3 then the player will use wav or mp3 via html5 if it can, or MP3 via flash as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the player div does not have display: none; Otherwise the swf will not be initialized.

Even if you hide the player during init() only. If you need to hide it, set position to absolute and left to -5000px;